# How to design IPhone application interface?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I am new with xcode. I want to create a simple interface in xcode like the above link  http://i52.tinypic.com/2ah8k7o.png. Now i am not understanding what xcode objects should i use and how can i use them. I am working on xcode 4.0.2

Please guide. Any code or web url would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a grid view. Try [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). The project demo is explanatory. You have to study it and customise according to your requirments.

Comment: Hi Praveen, can you please guide me, what book/videos or etc materiel i can refer to best start to work with IPhone?

Comment: Learn Objective-C first, then move to iOS. "Programming in Objective-C" and "iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" are good books.

Comment: yaa i have Objective-c experience. Please guide for next step. I mean for iOS Programming.

Comment: I started off on iOs 6 months ago. Now i have 4 apps on itunes. So if you need my advice, read first few chapters from any tutorial out there and start implementing. Thats the best way to learn.

Comment: Ok since you have experience, the AQGrid view is extension of uitableview. Set up the delegates and datsource and then you can get the screen you want.

Comment: Many Thanks @Praveen for your guidance. I will follow you.

Answer (score 1):

You should read iOS Human Interface Guidelines : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf

Comment: In case someone is still looking for legendary MobileHIG pdf file it can still be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140826141448/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf or here https://www.evl.uic.edu/datsoupi/420_14/docs/MobileHIG.pdf